# Get times with hours > 24

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am trying to convert a time duration, stringified as "3h30m" (for example), into the individual hours and minutes component. I want to allow hours to be greater than 23

```
time.strptime("3h30m", "%Hh%Mm")
```

The above returns a `time.struct_time` where `tm_hour=3` and `tm_min=30`.

If I try:

```
time.strptime("25h30m", "%Hh%Mm")
```

I get a `ValueError`. Is it possible to run the above and get a `tm_hour=25`?

Comment: Isn't the max value of hour 23?

Comment: @Psidom I don't want it to be

Comment: No, by defenition: `%H`:  "Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   00, 01, ..., 23"

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Then I guess you can use regular expression to get the number by yourself instead of using time module.

Comment: My opinion: "25h30m" is not a time, it is a time duration. For that you can use `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: Could you explain in what context it is used - and with what purpose -?

Comment: yeah, I am using it as a time duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up using a regex:

```
def parse_time_span(time_string):
    """Convert an inputted string representing a timespan, like 3h30m15s, into a duration in seconds."""
    pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:(?P<hours>\d+)h)?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+)m)?(?:(?P<seconds>\d+)s)?$")
    (hours, minutes, seconds) = pattern.match(time_string).groups()
    hours = 0 if hours is None else int(hours)
    minutes = 0 if minutes is None else int(minutes)
    seconds = 0 if seconds is None else int(seconds)
    total_seconds = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds).total_seconds()
    return round(total_seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `time.strptime()` for that, `%H` can only represent a number between 0 and 23. The time tuple format doesn't support `tm_hour` values > 23 either.

You could use a regular expression instead:

```
import re

def parse_time(inputtext, _pattern=re.compile(r'(?:(\d+)h)?([0-5]\d)m')):
    try:
        hours, minutes = _pattern.search(inputtext).groups()
    except AttributeError:
        raise ValueError('Not a valid time string')
    return int(hours or 0), int(minutes)
```

The above pattern works for any hours and minutes combination, with minutes up to 59 and hours unlimited (and omitting them altogether works too).

```
>>> parse_time('25h82m')  # invalid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in parse_time
ValueError: Not a valid time string
>>> parse_time('25h30m')  # valid
(25, 30)
>>> parse_time('3h30m')  # valid
(3, 30)
>>> parse_time('30m')  # valid
(0, 30)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just because you want it does not mean it is possible in this framework. As @Psidom said, you will need to do the work to parse out what you care about.

The regex for your hour would be:

```
[0-9]*h
```

And minute:

```
[0-9]*m
```

Using regex in py can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).